# Whether a function is globally 1-1.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is given by, $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2,x^3+y^3+z^3)$ where $U=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}: x>y>z\}$.

1. Is the function globally $1-1$?
2. If $K\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be compact then will $f^{-1}(K)$ comapct?

Here $$Df(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 & 1\\ 2x& 2y & 2z\\ 3x^2& 3y^2&3z^2 \end{bmatrix}$$ determiant is non-zero, so it is locally $1-1$. But how do I determine whether it is globally $1-1$ or not?

Comment: Try to solve $f(x_1,y_1,z_1)=f(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. The task for this particular choice of $f$ is actually quite enlightening

Comment: Do you know about symmetric polynomials?

Comment: No, I don't know.

Comment: But the det is zero if two variables are equal.

Comment: No, I changed my $U$.

Comment: Say $x\neq y$. What what are the values of $f(x,y,z)$ and $f(y,x,z)$?

Comment: It is given that $x\neq y\neq z,$ see my edited $U$.

Comment: okay both are same, hence it is not globally $1-1$.

Comment: Given $f(x,y,z)$ then $x,y,z$ are the solutions to a third degree polynomial, and with the new U this determines the variables uniquely.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri You cant switch x and y and still be on U.

Comment: okay, yes true.

Comment: I suppose you can deal with question $2$ on your own, but I can help if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to look at the problem as follows.

> **Claim:** Let $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\in \mathbb{C}$.
>   Consider the system of $n$ equations on $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$
>
> $$p_k(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}^k = a_k,$$
>
> where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.
>   Then, up to permutation, the solution of the system is unique.

*Proof:* Let $S=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a solution to the system and consider

$$q_S(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-x_i).$$

There are constants $c_0,\dots,c_{n-1}\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $q_S(X)=X^n+c_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\dots+c_1X+c_0$.
By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have that for $k=1,\dots,n-1$

$$e_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)={(-1)}^k\,c_{n-k},$$

where the $e_k$ are [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).

By [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), the $e_k$ can be expressed in terms of the [power sum symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) $p_k$, whose values are prescribed by the hypotheses of the claim.
It follows that the constants $c_{n-k}$ depend only on the $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$.

This means that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are solutions to our system, the polynomials $q_{S_1}(X)$ and $q_{S_2}(X)$ are equal.
In other words, there is a polynomial $q$ such that every solution $S=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to our system satisfies $q(x_i)=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

Up to permutation, this uniquely defines the $x_i$ as roots (with multiplicity) of $q$, which completes the proof. $\square$

---

We can now show that $f$ is in fact one-to-one.
Indeed, by the claim we have that $f(x_1,y_1,z_1) =$ $f(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ if and only if $\{x_1,y_1,z_1\}=\{x_2,y_2,z_2\}$.
Since the domain of $f$ requires that $x_i>y_i>z_i$, it follows that we must have $x_1=x_2$, $y_1=y_2$ and $z_1=z_2$.